# Create an Ubuntu server on Ubuntu desktop

Tags: server

Apologies if this is a basic question, but is it possible to use my Ubuntu 20.04 desktop to create an Ubuntu server "on the side"?

I am relying on AWS EC2 at the moment, and it is starting to cost me.

This could be some kind of Ubuntu VM that has ports opened (I suppose but again, Ubuntu nb), but I am more thinking of some regular server creation on my desktop.

Comment: Yes, absolutely. There is a Ubuntu Server version that lacks a desktop and had some server management packages preinstalled, but there is no reason you can't use your desktop system as a server.

Comment: What are the uses of the AWS VM you currently have and what do you need the ports open for? Depending on that and if you a have a static or dynamic IP I can provide a more concrete answer below.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I am currently hosting 2 web applications on AWS but I would like to host them directly on my computer (they are very low traffic, used for background tasks so no worries). I would just like to create a server on my desktop and host them here. @m_krsic sorry I did a mistake on my question, I was thinking about some sort of VM but as you both pointed out there is no need, so if I may rephrase, how can I create a very low requirement server on my desktop machine to host these 2 webapps. 
Many thanks

Comment: You say a web application: that suggests that you should install Apache2, PHP and MySQL. Then you find a way to route traffic from the internet to your system (assuming it isn't directly connected, which you don't want, generally) and you're on your way.

Comment: Thanks, will be Nginx since the app is on Django. Any tips on how not to  directly connect to the internet the server while keeping the Desktop part functionning?

Comment: You can use your own system, a container like docker, or a VM. I suggest you first use Docker or VM so you get more familiar because you don't want to exoose your system bare metal without proper knowledge & configuration, ir mess up your system unnecessarily